# Next.js + Webpack: Attempting to import 3rd party SCSS into project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I am attempting to use this cool [React Button Component](https://github.com/rcaferati/react-awesome-button) inside my project but I do not understand where I am going wrong and how my [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#example) isn't working. Please could you help! I am also new at Webpack and I would appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction. Much Thanks :)

[image: Getting this 404 error message]

I get this **error message**:

```
[ error ] ./node_modules/react-awesome-button/src/styles/styles.scss 2:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| // [Default] Variables
> @import './base/variables.scss';
| // [Default] Custom Properties
| @import './base/custom-properties.scss';
```

**Package.json**

```
  {
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "9.0.8",
    "react": "16.10.2",
    "react-awesome-button": "^6.1.2",
    "react-dom": "16.10.2",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-cgb": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "4.36.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
  }
}
```

**Webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); //installed via npm
const webpack = require('webpack'); //to access built-in plugins

module.exports = {
    entry: './pages/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'my-first-webpack.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.txt$/,
                use: 'raw-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    // style-loader
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    // css-loader
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: true
                        }
                    },
                    // sass-loader
                    { loader: 'sass-loader' }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
                    'style-loader',
                    // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                    'css-loader',
                    // Compiles Sass to CSS
                    'sass-loader',
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './src/index.html' })
    ],
    mode: 'production'
};
```

**Breaks on this line:**

```
 import AwesomeButtonStyles from "react-awesome-button/src/styles/styles.scss";
```

Comment: It might be something with the library itself. Thought it looked cool indeed, so tried to install it. I'm getting the following:
`ERROR in ./node_modules/react-awesome-button/src/components/AwesomeButtonProgress/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: node_modules/react-awesome-button/src/components/AwesomeButtonProgress/index.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (10:20):` thought im defenitely using classProperties syntax all over my project

Comment: I followed this [link](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-sass). It removes the error but it doesn't apply the css? I feel that the library might be the issue as well or I am missing something important.

Answer (score 0):

The styles file that you're importing to your HTML, is it a .css extension or .scss extension?  If you're just using .scss files then you need to change your test Regex in your webpack folder to look for that extension.

```
 test: /\.scss$/
```

If however you're using files with both extension types, then you'll want to use a test value like below.  The question mark looks for 0 or more occurrences of the s, so it will work for scss and css files.

```
 test: /\.s?css$/
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: The file that I want to import is a .scss extension. Both of those solutions somehow give me the same output as above.

Comment: Interesting.  I don't have too much experience with Next.js, which is what it looks like you're using.  Looking at the documentation it seems as though Next.js has its own library for compiling SASS files.  Check out this link https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-sass.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: That removes the error but it doesn't apply the css?
I removed the webpack.config.js and implemented next.config.js

`const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
module.exports = withSass({
  cssModules: true,
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    importLoaders: 1,
    localIdentName: "[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
  }
})`